# How can I secure socket in NetMQ/ZeroMQ?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, zeromq, netmq

I'm using Router-Dealer and Pub-Sub patterns to send and receive messages using TCP(tcp://).

The Server-Client communication is working fine and now I need to secure this socket connection over a network.

**How can I make the connection secure in NetMQ/ZeroMQ?**

Is it possible to use SslStream to secure the sockets in NetMQ ?
Or any other better mechanism which we can use to secure the socket connection?

If anybody has any idea, please help me.
Helpful answers are much appreciated.

Comment: Simplest way is to encrypt message before sending and then decrypt after receiving.

Comment: Also see following : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000189/A-Working-TCP-Client-and-Server-With-SSL?force_isolation=true

Comment: ZeroMQ offers the [CURVE](http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-curve) mechanism for secure communication.